# C# - Stopping timer from another method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn OOP with C#. Target framework: .net core 3.1.
I have two classes. In the first one I initialize timer:

```cs
public class Test
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    public void Begin()
    {
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Action);
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Start();
    }
    public virtual void Action(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running");
    }

    public void Finish()
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

and in the main class I have two methods for starting timer and for stopping timer

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start();

        ConsoleKeyInfo input;
        do
        {
            input = Console.ReadKey();
        } while (input.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

        Console.WriteLine("Stopping");
        Stop();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Start()
    {
        Test a = new Test();
        a.Begin();
        Console.WriteLine("Started");
    }

    static void Stop()
    {
        Test a = new Test();
        a.Finish();
        Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
    }
}
```

Why the timer keeps running after it is stopped and disposed?

Comment: Start and Stop create two separate instances of Test class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close! As Chamika pointed out in the comments, you're interacting with two different instances of your `Test` class. The `new` keyword means just that, a `new` instance is created of `Test`.

To correct this, you can create either a `global variable` or pass the instance to your `Start()` and `Stop()` methods.

First, I'm going to show the `global variable` solution.

---

Without editing your `Test` class, I've modified your `Program` class. I've created a `global variable`: `myTimer`. `myTimer` is set to a new instance of the `Test` class. I also removed the other instance creations from your `Start()` and `Stop()` methods. Because they are in the same `Program` class, they will be able to interact with your `global variable` whether it's set to `public` or `private`!

```cs
    class Program
    {
        // Global variable to use within the class. 
        //  - This maintains the correct/same instance of the Test() class 
        //  - to interact with, starting/stopping.
        public static Test myTimer = new Test();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Start();

            ConsoleKeyInfo input;
            do
            {
                input = Console.ReadKey();
            } while (input.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

            Console.WriteLine("Stopping");
            Stop();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Start()
        {
            // I removed the Test a = new Test() line as it creates 
            // - a 'new' instance of the Test() class

            // Set the instance to interact with to the global variable: myTimer
            myTimer.Begin();
            Console.WriteLine("Started");
        }

        static void Stop()
        {
            // I removed the Test a = new Test() line as it creates 
            // - a 'new' instance of the Test() class

            // Set the instance to interact with to the global variable: myTimer
            myTimer.Finish();
            Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
        }
   }

// Output:
//  Started
//  Running
//  Running
//  Running
//  ... 
//  Stopping
//  Stopped
```

---

Here is the `passing variable` solution just for another way to think about it!

About the same amount of changes are made, just in a different manner. The `Test` class is still not been touched or altered.

Instead of creating a `global variable`, add the `arguments` to your `methods` so they expect an instance of `Test` to be passed. Create the instance within your `Main` method and then pass the variable.

```cs
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create the instance of the 'Test' class. 
            // Since this is created in the 'Main' scope, passing it to 
            // Start() and Stop() will use this instance.
            Test myTimer = new Test();

            // Pass 'myTimer' to Start() to start timer
            Start(myTimer);

            ConsoleKeyInfo input;
            do
            {
                input = Console.ReadKey();
            } while (input.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

            Console.WriteLine("Stopping");
            // Pass 'myTimer' to Stop() to stop timer
            Stop(myTimer);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Start(Test myTimer)
        {
            myTimer.Begin();
            Console.WriteLine("Started");
        }

        static void Stop(Test myTimer)
        {
            myTimer.Finish();
            Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
        }
  }

// Output:
//  Started
//  Running
//  Running
//  Running
//  ... 
//  Stopping
//  Stopped
```

Comment: @vdt , I hope it helps! If it works for you, make sure to mark as answer to close out the question! :) Happy Coding!